# Accessing Rows from Access Database in Visual Basic 2010 based on Combobox Selection

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, row, range

I've been looking for 3 days but I can't find what I need. I am rusty but I work for a company that manages I.T. for hotels. I have an access database that has a column with HOTELNAME, Street, Zip, Phone, etc etc.

The hotel names are populating a combobox on my form. Basically once the user picks the hotel from the drop down I want all of the info from the other rows (matching the row of the selected item) such as location info and phone, to populate a few LABELS but I can't seem to find what code I need for the labels.

CODE:
Public Class Newticket

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.HotelsdbTableAdapter.Fill(Me.HotelsDataSet1.hotelsdb)

    Try
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
        ("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\David_2\Desktop 2\Skosh\hotelDB.xlsx'; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter _
            ("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)

        ' cmbHotels.Items.Add = Sheet1$.Range("A1").Text

        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try



End Sub


Private Sub Newticket_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FrmMain.Hide()

End Sub
Private Sub NewTicket_Disposed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed
    FrmMain.Show()
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub lblHotel_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblHotel.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblPoc.Click

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Label7_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label7.Click

End Sub

Private Sub BindingSource1_CurrentChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub cmbHotels_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbHotels.SelectedIndexChanged




End Sub

Private Function Sheets(p1 As String) As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function

Private Function Rows() As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function

Private Function Sheet1() As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub BindingSource1_CurrentChanged_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BindingSource1.CurrentChanged

End Sub

Private Sub FillByHotelToolStripButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Try
        Me.HotelsdbTableAdapter.FillByHotel(Me.HotelsDataSet1.hotelsdb)
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Basically pick a hotel from combobox. A few labels on  the right with contat info need to populate the hotels info. I have 0 idea what to do for the labels. the combobox is working.

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically like this ..

```
Private Sub cmbHotels_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbHotels.SelectedIndexChanged
If cmbHotels.SelectedIndex = -1 then exit sub

Dim sHotel As String = cmbHotels.Text
Dim dr As DataRow

MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter _
        ("select * from [Sheet1$] where HotelName = '" & sHotel & "'" ,MyConnection) 

DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)

dr = DtSet.Rows(0)

'fill your label now
lblStreet.Text = dr.item("Stree") '----- or whatever
'etc

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it today and see how it works. Seems straightforward enough!

Comment: BTW I've switched from Excel to an ACCESS Database. Is the code the same?